# How to add extra key-value to QuerySet lists?

Tags: python, django

I am working with Django,i need to retrieve data from multiple database, which has different database name but with same table column structure.
So I use `model.using(database).all()`to get `queryset` and merge them into one.
I want to add extra `databasename` to indicate the data's database name, this is my code.
model:

```
class Sections(models.Model):
    apply_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pathology_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    user_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

get_queryset:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    slideset = []
    database_config = ['database1', 'database2', 'database3']
    for i, x in database_config:
        slides = Sections.objects.using(x).all()
        #### I want to add extra databasename column in every query object.
        for x1 in slides:
            x1.databasename = x
        ######
        slideset.append(slides)
    
    # merge QuerySet
    query = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a|b, slideset)
    return query.order_by("updated_at").reverse()
```

the one return will be :

```
  {
        "apply_id": 1123,  
        "pathology_id": 1235,  
        "user_id": 1,  
        "updated_at": "202106011430",  
        # add extra databasename. 
        "databasename": "database1". 
    }
```

Because the column can't be modify, so I had to leave `Sections` model unchange, just add extra key-value to query, can someone help me on that?

Comment: `from django.db.models import Value` and `slides = Sections.objects.using(x).annotate(databasename=Value(x))`

Comment: I tried with your way and get exception with: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field`

Comment: @GuiHva what version of Django do you use? Try `from django.db.models import CharField, Value` and `slides = Sections.objects.using(x).annotate(databasename=Value(x, output_field=CharField()))` (The output field is not needed in Django versions 3.2 onwards)

Comment: django==3.1.8, and the return exception is: `TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): <django.db.models.fields.CharField>`

Comment: @GuiHva please check the code in the comment _carefully_ the `output_field=CharField()` is passed to _`Value`_ not to `annotate`.

Comment: yes, my bad. thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Abdul Aziz Barkat

use `annotate`

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value
slides = Sections.objects.using(x).annotate(databasename=Value(databasename, output_field=CharField())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a list of queryset object of users as you know we can take only that parms in values list wich is presents inside own model. but in my case i need one more key value pair, I tried to put directly inside in the values() then we will get an key error. to over come this problem see in below:

I have user Case with when inside annotate

```
from django.db.models import F, When, Case, BooleanField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
users_list = User.objects.filter(registration__status=status_type).values(
        'id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',).annotate(is_logged_in=Case(When(
            email=request.user.email, then=True),default=False, output_field=BooleanField()))
```

OutPut:

```
{
  "id": XX,
  "username": "demo.user",
  "first_name": "Demo",
  "last_name": "User",
  "email": "xxxx.xxxxx@XXXXX.com",
  "phone_number": "111111111",
  "is_logged_in": true
},
```

As you can see i have added one extra key value in the above json "is_logged_in": True (only for logged in user) rest of the user false